# Leaks tool not finding leaks, but memory is not freeing

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

For example, I use NSXMLParser with input stream. When parser loads xml node application created NSManagedObject according this node. If counter(simple NSInteger property) of created managed objects is more than 50, application saves managed object context, then take all gathered objects in array and do **refreshObject: obj mergeChanges:NO**(there objects turning to faults)
After full loading to db app do same things for faulting and then resets context stored in property and nullified it and flushing all of references to managed objects.
As a result: 50000 of objects are saved, but memory freed partially, not fully(~20 megabytes remains).
Import to coredata doing in background thread where much of @autorelease's.
Leaks tool not showing leaks. I cannot figure out why memory not freeing after that manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaks aren't the only reason for memory growing, there is also abandoned memory. That means that you are still referencing and object with a pointer, but you are not using anymore. To find them here is a [help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Finding_Abandoned_Memory/07_Finding_Abandoned_Memory.html). 
There is also another thing that you should check out: autoreleased objects. These kind of objects are reference into a pool. The pool retains them until is drained.
 Since you are doing a parsing, most probably you are creating a lot of autoreleased objects, those objects will be released in some time in the future (probably during the next run loop), but you can help them to be released earlier by creating your own pool. For instance you can start your pool right before the parse start and close it right after the end. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) are more info on how use them.

Comment: Another thread that doing importing to database is covered by autorelease pool. Then I marked generations as it recommended in apple's article. Some generations viewed me main() of main thread and after analysing says "100%"(what it mean?). But it only one time. In other times generations contains only libsystem_c.dylib calls

Comment: Since you are doing some operations on a secondary thread, are you sure that you didn't make a retain cycle?

Comment: Is it no warranty that in the case "leaks tool" can find leak? So I'm using dispatch_async in global queue. It is bad idea? Managed context created, edited and destroyed in same detached thread

Comment: Is difficult for leaks not finding a leak. Is better if you start to show some code

Comment: I found reason! It occurs because code does fetch requests for parents of created object then sets corresponding parent for created object and then make reference cycle. setIncludesChildren:NO in fetch request resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons why, and many of them could have to do with your code. There are a couple other possibilities. You could have zombies enabled, which would prevent the memory from being freed. Also, CoreData retains objects as needed as well.

Comment: Zombies is disabled, I checked for it. Is coreData retaining objects regardless of my code?